# Re-creating a C# Solution from a .exe

Tags: visual-studio, reflector

A few years ago we had a small program created for generating reports (written in C#, probably Visual Studio 2008) - it is a Windows Forms exe with a couple of dll files.

I need to make a change to the hard-coded value of VAT but we cannot find the source code for this file anywhere. Is there a way to re-load this exe + dlls into a Visual Studio project?

I have some experience with .Net Reflector, but would that be the answer to building a new solution?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to google *.Net decompiler*, it should give you what you are searching for.

Comment: I can suggest you [Telerik Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) that can also create the Visual Studio project and it is free

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I tried Telerik but it did not output a 'build-able' solution. After watching some videos I was able to Decompile the .exe and create a 'build-able' solution using .Net Reflector.